# html javascript toggle navbar from bottom up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, toggle

I've workout a way to toggle the side bar menu from left to right. Below is the coding:

https://jsfiddle.net/2z84zyjz/3/

But I can't find a way to make it toggle from bottom up. Do you guys have any idea?

`Toggle`

Comment: i've changed `left` to `top` - https://jsfiddle.net/2z84zyjz/5/ you can adjust further using `height`

Comment: I've tested your solution. But it seems like my wrapper already gone to bottom initially. What I want is there's another div coming up from bottom. Something like when u press the bottom a keyboard slides up. any ideas?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2z84zyjz/8/ does this look like something you were trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" class="container-fluid toggled">
        <div class="navbar"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Toggle</a>  
        <a class="navbar-brand">Heading <span id="counterId"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    padding-top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    background-color:aqua;
    height:400px;
}
#header.toggled {
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#header").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
```

Refer this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c209beer/1/

Comment: Seems like this solution is sliding from top to bottom. But what I'm interested is sliding from bottom to top. Any ideas?

Comment: This solution seems like sliding from top to bottom. What I'm interested to do is something sliding from bottom to top. Like when we press a button a keyboard will be sliding from bottom to top. Any ideas?

Comment: The fiddle which i have attached does the job. Please verify.

Answer (score 1):

```js
            $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $(".navbar").slideUp();
            });
            $('#menu-toggle').dblclick(function(e) {
              $(".navbar").slideDown();
            });
```

```css
        #wrapper {
          padding-left: 0;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
          background-color: aqua;
          height: 400px;
        }
        #wrapper.toggled {
          padding-top: 250px;
        }
        #sidebar-wrapper {
          z-index: 1000;
          position: fixed;
          left: 250px;
          width: 0;
          height: 100%;
          margin-left: -250px;
          overflow-y: auto;
          background: #050545;
          -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
          transition: all 0.5s ease;
          box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 10px -7px grey;
        }
        #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
          height: 250px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid" style="padding-top:100px;"> <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle">Toggle</a>

    <div class="navbar"> <a class="navbar-brand">Heading <span id="counterId"></span></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper"></div>
```

Use the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods to show/hide your navbar

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z84zyjz/4/)

Comment: or you could use slideToggle look at http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/

Comment: I'm interested in your solution. But I don't like to double click to slide down. Any idea how to use toggle to slide up and down?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the **'keyboard'** scenario working on a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2z84zyjz/8/).

`padding-top` and `height` are the key players here.

Whatever customization you might need can be worked out from there as your sliding problem would've been resolved.

The following are my changes to the OP's original fiddle

HTML

```
<div id="keyboard">KEYBOARD</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#header {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    padding-top: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper.toggled #header {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
#keyboard {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height:160px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

As you can see it is only a matter of **hierarchy** and **manipulating** the correct `properties` - as in this case `padding-top` and `height`
Hope it helps someone else who might(someday) have this specific issue.
[Edit: updated post to be more than a 'link only' answer to a 'link only' question]

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

In your example change:

```
#wrapper.toggled {
            padding-left: 250px;
        }
```

to

```
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-top: 250px;
 }
```

Comment: Tried already. It shows sliding from top to bottom. What I want is sliding from bottom to top. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no difference between sliding top-bottom or bottom-top except for the positioning of the element. Here is a fiddle that shows what you are asking for: https://jsfiddle.net/dv0psgj9/

Comment: I need a slide from bottom to top effect because when I press the button, a keyboard will slide from bottom to top. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: This request is different to what you originally asked. I suggest that you edit your question and include this. For what it is worth I have developed an input-linked keyboard a while ago on Github you might find it useful: https://github.com/kalimah-apps/kalimah-keys